# COMPLEX Context handling in XSLT

Tags: xslt

REPOSTING as it's a different requirement from my previous question..

Hi XSLT Gurus,

I have a bit of a complex requirement. I need to get the values from another node while using the context from another node.
Please see sample below:

```
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>111</epc>
  <epc>222</epc>
 </epcList>
 <material>ABC</material>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>333</epc>
 </epcList>
 <material>DEF</material>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>containerFOR111222</epc>
 </epcList>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>containerFOR333</epc>
 </epcList>
</ObjectEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
 <parentID>containerFOR111222</parentID>
 <childEPCs>
  <epc>111</epc>
  <epc>222</epc>
 </childEPCs>
</AggregationEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
 <parentID>containerFOR333</parentID>
 <childEPCs>
  <epc>333</epc>
 </childEPCs>
</AggregationEvent>
```

The number of parent nodes will depend on the unique materials. so in this case there will be 2. Output should be something like this:

```
<MATERIAL>
 <BATCH>ABC</BATCH>
 <SERIES>
  <TOTAL>2</TOTAL>
  <EPCS>
   <EPC>111</EPC>
   <CONTAINER>containerFOR111222</CONTAINER>
  </EPCS>
  <EPCS>
   <EPC>222</EPC>
   <CONTAINER>containerFOR111222</CONTAINER>
  </EPCS>
 </SERIES>
</MATERIAL>
<MATERIAL>
 <BATCH>DEF</BATCH>
 <SERIES>
  <TOTAL>1</TOTAL>
  <EPCS>
   <EPC>333</EPC>
   <CONTAINER>containerFOR333</CONTAINER>
  </EPCS>
 </SERIES>
</MATERIAL>
```

I already got the MATERIAL, BATCH, SERIES, TOTAL, EPCS and EPC right. The problem is with the CONTAINER field. I cannot get the value of the 2nd context (containerFOR333). I'm just getting the value of the 1st context :(

This is the mapping i have now. I don't have an idea for CONTAINER:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ObjectEvent/material">
 <MATERIAL>
  <BATCH>
   <xsl:value-of select="./material"/>
  </BATCH>
  <SERIES>
   <TOTAL>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(./epcList/epc"/>
   </TOTAL>
    <xsl:for-each select="./epcList/epc">
     <EPCS>
      <EPC>
       <xsl:value-of select="./epcList/epc"/>
      </EPC>
      <CONTAINER>???</CONTAINER>
      </EPCS>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </SERIES>
 </MATERIAL>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My actual source, target message and mapping is much much more complex than this so hopefully ill be able to start with a simple solution then work my way up to the higher complexities

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xsl:key` to build a map from an arbitrary identifier to an element.

The following template uses the first `epc` element in each `AggregationEvent` as a key for the event's `parentID`. It's then used to look up the `parentID` related to the first `epc` in the `material` event.

This assumes that the first `epc` is always present and is unique.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="epc-key" match="parentID" use="../childEPCs/epc[1]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ObjectEvent/material">
            <MATERIAL>
                <BATCH>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </BATCH>
                <SERIES>
                    <TOTAL>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(../epcList/epc)"/>
                    </TOTAL>
                    <EPCS>
                        <xsl:for-each select="../epcList/epc">
                            <EPC>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </EPC>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <CONTAINER>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('epc-key', ../epcList/epc[1])"/>
                        </CONTAINER>
                    </EPCS>
                </SERIES>
            </MATERIAL>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```